# Java Map where the Value is a List of values of the same type as the key

Tags: java, generics, collections

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
public abstract Class Content {
    private Map<Class<? extends Content>, List<? extends Content>> relations;
}
```

Content has a bunch of subclasses - A,B,C,D etc...

The most frequent use case is to get all A's:

```
public List<A> getA() {
    return (List<A>)relations.get(A.class);
}
```

Kind of ok - apart from the ugly cast.

But the real problem is there's nothing stopping me from doing something stupid like:

```
relations.put(A.class, List<B> myListOfBs);
```

So a call to getA() above would result in a horrible cast exception. Is there any way I can write it so the compiler would warn me in the above example - and also remove the need for the ugly cast.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper around a `Map` and use a generic method to constrain your put method:

```
 public class HeterogeneousContainer {
     private final Map<Class<? extends Content>, List<? extends Content>> map;

     public <T extends Content> void put(Class<T> type, List<T> values) {
         map.put(type, values);
     }


     public <T extends Content> List<T> get(Class<T> type) {
         //this warning can be safely suppressed after inspection
         return (List<T>) map.get(type); 
     }
 }
```

Now you know that as long as the users of the container aren't using it improperly (i.e. in raw form) then the key and value must correspond...you couldn't call `put(B.class, listOfAs);`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `Map` interface that fixes the type to the *same* type:

```
interface RelatedMap<T> extends Map<Class<T>, List<T>> {}
```

then

```
private RelatedMap<? extends Content> relations;
```

Comment: This seems like a cool idea, but doesn't actually work in practice.  You can't add anything to `relations` because Java can't deal with the capture problem.  E.g. you can't do `RelatedMap<? extends CharSequence> relations; relations.put(String.class, new ArrayList<String>());`.

Comment: Also it can't work because it would be type unsafe: `RelatedMap<String> strings; RelatedMap<?> anything = strings; anything.put(Integer.class, Arrays.asList(1, 2)); String str = strings.values().iterator().next().get(0);` <-- type error